# Get frequency of data from two columns via one SQL query

Tags: mysql

I have the table
`_______________
| from  |  to  |
|   1   |   2  |
|   2   |   2  |
|   1   |   2  |
|   3   |   2  |`

Where `from` and `to` are countries.

I need to get top 10 countries met in `from` and `to`.
The result would be
`________________
|country| count |
|   2   |   5   |
|   1   |   2   |
|   3   |   1   |`

I reached what I need in two queries, but I am almost sure there is possibility to manage it with one.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a `UNION ALL` and then `GROUP BY` using the union of from and to:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(*) AS count FROM
  (SELECT from AS country FROM table_name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT to AS country FROM table_name)
GROUP BY country 
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 10
```